# Getting rid of the Refresh on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, postback

I have a asp:Button that has an `onclick` function. Is there a way to eliminate the refresh that occurs?

Current HTML containing button.

```
<div id="user" class="font">
                <div id="userPanel">

            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch"  runat="server" Width="400px" align="left"></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:Button  ID="searchbutton" text="enter" runat="server" 
                onclick="searchbutton_Click" />

            <asp:Label ID="test" runat="server"></asp:Label>

            </div>

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="userinfoupdatepanel" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="topcontent">
                        <ul>...</ul>
                    </div> 
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The button click then calls a function that fills the UL content

Comment: Do you want to call only a javascript function, but to postback the page?

Comment: It actually calls a function in c# currently

Comment: Ok, and you want it to do nothing at all?

Comment: I want it to do something.  Do I have the wrong definition of postback?  I want to eliminate the darn blink when the user clicks the button and it loads the information.  I originally had it not blink when I had users choose from a list but I changed it to a button and it keeps occuring.

Comment: Yes, you are misunderstanding postback. A postback is when the **client** (that is, the browser) **posts** the page back to the server. Actually, **POST** is a HTTP verb with a really deeper meaning, but, for now, let's put it this way. When a page is *postedback* to the server, you are able to run some C# code, like that delegate that you have for the `onclick` event. So, now that you know what a postback is and why you need it, tell me again: what do you want with your button?

Comment: Actually, that "darn blink" you are talking may be related to **SmartNavigation**. Please, check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.smartnavigation(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. Yes, I originally had an ajax update panel around the list box that would update fields when a name was chosen in the list box. It did this without having to blink, where as when I changed it to a txtBox and a button, it always blinks before the information is displayed. Both called a c# function.

Also, checking out the link now

Comment: Forget about the link, now it's clear: you're using Ajax. Please, update your question with your markup (that is, `<body>` and so on) so we can point why is it *refreshing* (that's the correct name).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OnClientClick` to bind a Javascript function to handle the click in the browser. If you return `false` from that fumction, the postback doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add client events using Attributes collection.

```
searchbutton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('Test')");
searchbutton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return fnSomeThing(this);");
```